# How to compare index value with database values in python mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, comparison

What I am doing is comparing a index value with the bar_code_no of database, if the bar_code_no is validated with the index value then I want to print the whole row of validated bar_code_no where I have name, email, phone.no. I tried it but the comparison is not possible.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
mydb1=mysql.connect(
        user = 'rajat',
        passwd = 'rajat',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'master_database'
        )
bal = []
validate =  ('1', 'Green', '12:34:56:78:91:22', '456456', '2')
val = validate[3]
bal.append(val)
print(bal)

new_list = []
mycursor3 = mydb1.cursor()
mycursor3.execute("SELECT bar_code_no FROM android_display_data")
df = mycursor3.fetchall()
print(df)

if bal in df:
    print('it exists')
else:
    print('it does not exists')
```

The output is like this:-

```
['456456']
[('456456',)]
it does not exists
```

Comment: why not just do df = mycursor3.fetchall("SELECT bar_code_no FROM android_display_data"), that way you can delete the extra line of "executing"

Comment: I tried sir, but I dont know why I am getting stuck, as this is not a big problem.

Comment: df = mycursor3.fetchall("SELECT bar_code_no FROM android_display_data") using this it shows a error --TypeError: fetchall() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: ok...I see, what I will suggest is doing a SELECT * FROM ... WHERE "bar_code_no" = bal (which is the value at index 3 in validate). you will have to make a change to the sql query which is one way of doing it, the * (star) gets you all the records, and you use WHERE as the depending condition.

Comment: could fix the __init__ to include an object for fetchall() or just change the class to @staticmethod, but I think in your case don't worry about the fetchall() just use execute() for now

Comment: using SELECT * FROM ... WHERE "bar_code_no" = bal (which is the value at index 3 in validate it shows empty list

Comment: Can you paste the updated sql query here, the WHERE is going to be like this:  
``WHERE table.`bar_code_no` = 456456``(hardcode, value at the index you are checking for)

Comment: sir, please check the answer I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of how to validate the values but still I got a problem that how to print the whole row in which the validated bar_code_no is present.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
mydb1=mysql.connect(
        user = 'rajat',
        passwd = 'rajat',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'master_database'
        )
bal = []
validate =  ('1', 'Green', '12:34:56:78:91:22', '456456', '2')
val = validate[3]
bal.append(val)
print(bal)

new_list = []
mycursor3 = mydb1.cursor()
mycursor3.execute("SELECT bar_code_no FROM android_display_data")
df = mycursor3.fetchall()
df1 = df[0]
df2 = list(df1)
print(df2)


if bal == df2:
    print('its exists')
else:
    print('it does not exist')
```